# Using timeouts inside a jQuery plugin while still maintaining chainability

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to create a jQuery plugin that has a timeout function inside of it. This is the basic idea of what I have now. It works fine, but it doesn't maintain chainability.

```
;(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(length) {
        th = $(this);
        th.css('animation', 'none');
        setTimeout((function(th) {
            return function() { 
                th.css('display', 'block');
            };
        })(this), length);
    };
})( jQuery );
```

To try and make it chainable I created this, but it doesn't run the code in the TimeOut function.

```
;(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(length) {
        return this.each(function() {
            th = $(this);
            th.css('animation', 'none');
            setTimeout((function(th) {
                return function() { 
                    th.css('display', 'block');
                };
            }),(this), length);
        });
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Here is the plugin working without chaining: http://jsfiddle.net/FhARs/1/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/delay/ ?

Comment: What does your plugin actually supposed to do? Can you produce a fiddle with it working (without chaining)?

Comment: @Lorax I updated the question to include a jsfiddle

Comment: @Adam Merrifield delay only works on functions in the effect queue. It doesn't work on css() or any actual javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is working, is this what you want ?

```
;(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(length) {
        return this.each(function() {
            th = $(this);
            th.css('display', 'none');
            setTimeout(function() {
                th.css('display', 'block');
            }, length);
        });
    };
})( jQuery );
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FhARs/2/).

Comment: @Mike, I also want to make sure that, the chained method here `css('color', red)` being applied before the `setTimeout` function being called but in this case you are hiding the element first so it looks like the style changed later, hope it's clear.